# Can duplication of encrypted characters lead to a weakness in RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key, implementation

Of course, I know RSA is to widely used and tested to have any legitimate threats, but I still am confused by this.

I have been trying to implement C++ (in a effort to *learn how it works*, not to be used in production), and I stumbled upon a C++ program online. When I run the program, it generates two random primes and uses it in the algorithm. The problem is that when the encrypted data goes by, each encrypted character is the same. Now, is this an implementation problem, or something else? Can someone please explain why this isn't considered a vulnerability?

An example -

```
YOUR TWO RANDOM PRIMES ARE 117 AND 127

ENTER A MESSAGE TO ENCRYPT: hello

ENCRYPTED: 
3146
3221
11184
11184
1662
```

Now, obviously an attacker (MiTM, to the best of my knowledge) can conclude that in the message, the third and fourth character in the message are the same.

To repeat, is this a problem with the RSA implementation? Is it overlooked because no one can logically conclude `11184` is `l`?

EDIT: I am aware that 117 and 127 are extremely to low to be used in anything that needs to be secure. The actual primes aren't relavant to my question unless they have something to do with why 11184 and 11184 are the same.

Answer (score 2):

> To repeat, is this a problem with the RSA implementation?

It would certainly not be overlooked; it would be considered a serious security issue.

Instead, it is an issue with this implementation; there are two ways this implementation isn't realistic:

For one, the primes is uses are extremely tiny.  Real implementations use primes that may be over 300 digits each (actually, we usually state the size of the primes in bits, not digits); with that, we can encrypt moderate sized messages directly; the string "hello" would easily fit.

For another (and more relevant), we always use randomized padding before doing RSA encryption.  That is, we don't give the string directly to the low level RSA function (which would have nonobvious security issues); instead, we convert the string into large integer, and include a number of random bits; these random bits mean that, even if we encrypt the same string multiple times, we'll always end up with different integers (and so at the end, every RSA encryption will look different).

Answer (score 0):

You are encrypting one character at a time and not padding or adding randomness. 
This is not a secure way of using RSA or in fact any cipher. Though normally we don't apply RSA to the message directly but rather use a symmetric cipher first and only use assymetric ciphers for the key. More important is padding. 
Any time you use RSA you want to add random padding to prevent not only identifying repeating but also related plain texts. 
Try reading about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding 
Which will protect against identifying repeat encryption of same message as well as many other potential attacks which may be possible with no/naive padding. This gives an all or nothing, if you don't have all of the padded message you can't get any information about the pre padding message.